# PHP pthreads: Add a new object from an "Threaded" to the pool

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads, php-7.1

I'm playing something around with pthreads 3.1.6-dev and PHP 7.1. My goal is to create a small webcrawler.

The planned workflow is: You put one URL into the pool (maybe the homepage) and a crawler (extends Threaded) fishes all links from this url. After small filtering the crawler should add all new links into the pool (no external links should be added to the pool). Alternatively the crawler give the new urls to "someone other" which adds it to the pool.

The process should continue until no new URLs are found.

My problem is that I found no working solution for this. My current draw looks like this: The crawler extract the urls and put it into the pool. For this holds every Worker a reference to the pool, so that the crawler can access over the worker the pool object.

The problem with this solution: If a "late" Threaded add a new Threaded to the pool, this new task will not performed.

Some demo code:

```
class WebWorker extends Worker
{
    public function __construct(WebPool $pool)
    {
        $this->pool = $pool;

        print_r("Create a new worker\n");
    }

    public function run()
    {
        print_r("Worker {$this->getThreadId()}: " . __METHOD__ . "\n");
    }

    public function getPool()
    {
        return $this->pool;
    }

    private $pool;
}

class WebWork extends Threaded
{
    public function run()
    {
        print_r("Webwork from Worker {$this->worker->getThreadId()}\n");

        if (rand(0, 10) > 5) {
            print_r("Webwork {$this->worker->getThreadId()} add new Webwork\n");

            $this->worker->getPool()->submit(new WebWork());
        }
    }
}

class WebPool extends Pool
{
    public function __construct($size, $class)
    {
        parent::__construct($size, $class, [$this]);
    }
}


$pool = new WebPool(2, 'WebWorker');
$pool->submit(new WebWork());
$pool->submit(new WebWork());
$pool->submit(new WebWork());
$pool->submit(new WebWork());

while ($pool->collect(function ($work) {
    return $work->isGarbage();
})) continue;

$pool->shutdown();
```

One example result:

```
Create a new worker
Worker 139878744053504: WebWorker::run
Webwork from Worker 139878744053504
Create a new worker
Worker 139878731872000: WebWorker::run
Webwork from Worker 139878731872000
Webwork from Worker 139878731872000
Webwork 139878731872000 add new Webwork
Webwork from Worker 139878744053504
Create a new worker
Worker 139878719289088: WebWorker::run
Webwork from Worker 139878719289088
Webwork 139878719289088 add new Webwork
```

Can someone tell me a best practice for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're relying on the garbage collector to block the main thread, when really you should be using your own condition to block on. Overriding the default garbage collector in pthreads v3 isn't really necessary except for special circumstances where you do not want the task to be collected immediately after it has finished executing.

One possible solution to your problem is to have a link counter variable that increments for every new link found (that needs crawling), and decrements for every link crawled. When this variable reaches 0, you can assume that the website has been fully crawled and therefore you can safely shut down your thread pool.

Here's this solution in code:

```
<?php

class WebsiteCrawler extends Worker
{
    public $pool; // expose the pool to our LinkCrawler tasks

    public function __construct(Pool $pool)
    {
        $this->pool = $pool;
    }
}

class LinkCrawler extends Threaded
{
    private $link;
    public static $domain;

    public function __construct(string $link)
    {
        $this->link = $link;
        WebCrawlerPool::$links[] = $link;
        ++WebCrawlerPool::$linksRemaining->count;
        var_dump($link); // for debugging, just to show that it is collecting links
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $content = file_get_contents($this->link);
        $domain = preg_quote(self::$domain);

        preg_match_all("~href=\"(.+?{$domain}.+?)\"~", $content, $matches); // naive regex to fetch links

        $links = $matches[1];

        foreach ($links as $link) {
            if (count(WebCrawlerPool::$links) > 9) { // stop at 10 links (for example purposes...)
                break;
            }
            if (!in_array($link, get_object_vars(WebCrawlerPool::$links), true)) {
                $this->worker->pool->submit(new LinkCrawler($link));
            }
        }

        --WebCrawlerPool::$linksRemaining->count;
    }
}

class WebCrawlerPool extends Pool
{
    public static $linksRemaining;
    public static $links;

    public function __construct(int $size, string $class, array $ctor = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($size, $class, [$this]);
        self::$links = new Threaded();
        self::$linksRemaining = new Threaded();
        self::$linksRemaining->count = 0;
    }
}

LinkCrawler::$domain = 'php.net';

$pool = new WebCrawlerPool(8, 'WebsiteCrawler');
$pool->submit(new LinkCrawler('http://php.net/', $pool)); // kick things off

while (WebCrawlerPool::$linksRemaining->count !== 0);

$pool->shutdown();

print_r(WebCrawlerPool::$links);
```

The above is, of course, just sample code - you may want to do things differently. But here are a couple of noteworthy points about it:

- The `$linksRemaining` is a `Threaded` object, rather than a simple integer. This is because `Threaded` objects have synchronization *built-in*. This means that many contexts can manipulate the same `Threaded` object safely. By leveraging this property of `Threaded` objects, you can simplify the code you write in pthreads.
- The links (`WebCrawlerPool::$links`) are held in a `Threaded` object that is created in the main context. This has been done for two reasons. Firstly, PHP arrays cannot be safely passed around and manipulated from multiple contexts (unlike `Threaded` obejcts). And secondly, `Threaded` objects are tied to the context they are created in. This means that we should create them in the outer-most context that we wish to use them in - otherwise, they will become unreachable when the thread that created them is joined.